# MySQL - Unknown column 'article.mycount' in 'where clause'

Tags: mysql

Good day guys,
I don't know... why does not this query works:

```
      SELECT article.topic, article.ID, 
      (
      SELECT COUNT(*) FROM comment
      WHERE article.ID_art = comment.foreign_ID_art
      GROUP BY foreign_ID_art
      ) 
      AS mycount

      FROM article
      WHERE article.mycount = '0'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT article.topic, article.ID, 
  (
  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM comment
  WHERE article.ID_art = comment.foreign_ID_art
  GROUP BY foreign_ID_art
  ) 
  AS mycount

FROM article
HAVING mycount = '0'
```

Comment: That looks good, but it does not works. It writes to me:
Unknown column 'article.mycount' in 'having clause'

Comment: My bad, it now should work. It should be just plain `HAVING mycount = '0'`

Comment: Thanks. If it helped you, vote up and accepting this as an answer is highly appreciated ^_^

Answer (score 1):

`mycount` is not a column of `article` table. The correct way to write it would be:

```
 SELECT article.topic,
        article.ID   ,
        ( SELECT  COUNT(*)
        FROM     COMMENT
        WHERE    article.ID_art = comment.foreign_ID_art
        GROUP BY foreign_ID_art
        )
        AS mycount
 FROM  article HAVING mycount = 0
```

An alternative way to achieve the same result, but in a way that could be a bit more efficient (given proper indexes exist):

```
SELECT article.topic,
       article.ID
FROM   article
       LEFT JOIN COMMENT
       ON     article.ID_art = comment.foreign_ID_art
WHERE  comment.foreign_ID_art IS NULL
```

Ultimately it would be best to just store the comment count for each article in `article` table as `comment_count` column and increment it whenever a new comment is added. Then the query could be simplified to:

```
SELECT article.topic,
       article.ID
FROM   article
WHERE  article.comment_count = 0
```

With an index on `comment_count` it would be very efficient.

Comment: That looks good (with HAVING), but it does not works. It writes to me:
Unknown column 'article.mycount' in 'having clause'

Comment: `HAVING mycount = 0` and not `HAVING article.mycount = 0`. `mycount` is not a column in `article`, so you cannot refer to it this way.

Comment: Thank you. ;-) Your first solution is same like user Andrius Naruševičius. But yours missing apostrophe. :-)

The second one helped me with using IS NULL and the last one is the best solution with using indexes.

Thank you so much for 3 different ways to solve that.

Comment: The apostrophe is not missing, because there should be none ;-) `mycount` is a number, so including an apostrophe around 0 means database has to do implicit type conversion (string to integer), which in this case is unnecessary work.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use column alias in where clause. Probably you can do something like

```
select *
(SELECT article.topic, article.ID,        
(       
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM comment       
WHERE article.ID_art = comment.foreign_ID_art       
GROUP BY foreign_ID_art       
)        
AS mycount        
FROM article) mytab       
from myab 
WHERE mytab.mycount = 0
```

Comment: And that is very difficult solution. ;-)